# Pattern to determine whether a given URL is for a Salesforce org

Tags: url, isv

My web application receives web hook registration requests for Salesforce instances. Applications other than Salesforce may also register a web hook. What pattern(s) could be used that would reliably distinguish the salesforce org urls from the other URLs? All the orgs that I have seen end in either "force.com" or "salesforce.com" but are there other possible domain names that could be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the reference of all URLs and domains [Allow the Required Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=setup_domains.htm&type=5)

> Salesforce uses these domains to deliver content.

- *.content.force.com
- *.force.com
- *.salesforce.com
- *.salesforceliveagent.com (used with Live Agent, Omni-Channel, and SOS)
- *.bluetail.salesforce.com

In addition, these domains are used to deliver content in the right frame of your login screen.

- *.sfdcstatic.com
- secure.eloqua.com
- www.google.*
- *.doubleclick.net
- www.facebook.com
- ssl.google-analytics.com

The right frame content is displayed in the followings URLs.

- login.salesforce.com
- test.salesforce.com
- .salesforce.com

A My Domain URL without custom branding (for example, norns.my.salesforce.com)